# "Function is not defined" - jQuery Plugins Question

Tags: jquery, plugins

I have a plugin in my plugins.js file that looks like this:

```
var ShowCredits=function(){var a={addEvent:function(b,c,d,e){if(b.addEventList ...etc
```

Over in my functions.js file I have this:

```
var credits = new ShowCredits();
credits.code = function() { ...etc
```

When I lint, I get the following error message:

```
var credits = new ShowCredits();
'ShowCredits' is not defined.
```

Which makes sense because of the way the plugin is written.

Is there a way to re-write this so that the code validates?

Thanks a lot,

-Yahreen

Answer (score 1):

The keyword `new` is to instantiate an object of the given class. Obviously, you don't define a class but a function. So just remove "new"

Comment: thanks, but because that function lives in the plugins file (at least as currently written), the code doesn't lint properly since it's not defined. I'm wondering if there's a cleaner way to write it so that it lints properly? I'd have to assume this is how the jQuery plugins system works, but I'm not that familiar with it?

Comment: Use /*jsl:import PathToOtherScript*/ to tell lint to load an external file